# AudioContext.outputLatency not supported in Safari: How do audiovisual apps handle bluetooth latency in Safari?

Tags: safari, bluetooth, synchronization, web-audio-api, audiocontext

I am developing an audio/visual web app. In order to synchronize the visual and audio elements of my app, when users are using bluetooth headphones, I make use of the web audio api's `AudioContext.baseLatency` value to offset the visual elements to synchronize with the audio received by the user.

This works great in Chrome and firefox: but is not implemented in Safari. I'm just curious how other apps deal with this. For example, Youtube playback on safari while wearing bluetooth headphones is perfectly synchronized. How do web developers obtain the latency information needed to perform this synchronization in Safari?

I have tried using `AudioContext.outputLatency`, but to no avail, since it is not implemented in Safari. ChatGPT suggested somehow taking advantage of WebRTC to figure this out, but I can't see how that would work.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: How large is the offset without using baseLatency?

Comment: With my bose quitecomfort in-ear headphones, the latency is about 0.3 seconds. Very noticeable.